Where is "lid close behavior" stored on gnome ubuntu?
Power settings like HandleLidSwitch and HandleLidSwitchExternalPower are stored in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. I had set these variables to hibernate; however, closing the laptop lid was suspending my system instead of hibernating. After some googling, I was able to fix the issue by running gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'hibernate'. That fixed my problem, however, I don't understand where power settings like lid-closing action are stored. I was expecting that all these settings are stored in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. What am I missing?
